# Передача двумерного массива в функцию (Rust)

Tags: массивы, функции, rust

Кто-нибудь может подсказать, как передать в функцию двумерный массив?

Желательно по ссылке, т.е. без копирования самого массива. К сожалению их "[книга](http://doc.rust-lang.org/1.0.0-beta/book/)" пока не богата на примеры передачи параметров в функцию. Вот как я себе это пытался представить:

```
fn foo(a:&[&[f64]],x:&[f64])
{
    for i in 0..3 {
        for j in 0..4 {
            println!("{}",a[i][j]);
        }
    }
}

fn main()
{
    let A:[[f64;4];3]=[[1.1,-0.2, 0.1,1.6],
                       [0.1,-1.2,-0.2,2.3],
                       [0.2,-0.1, 1.1,1.5]];
    let mut X:[f64;3]=[0.0;3];

    foo(&A,&X);
}
```

"X" передается без проблем, а вот на "А" ругается при всех комбинациях **[ ]** и **&**, которые я смог придумать:

```
src/main.rs:16:6: 16:8 error: mismatched types:
 expected `&[&[f64]]`,
    found `&[[f64; 4]; 3]`
(expected slice,
    found array of 3 elements) [E0308]
src/main.rs:16  foo(&A,&X);
                    ^~
error: aborting due to previous error
Could not compile `example`.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Дело в том, что, к примеру, выражение `[1i32, 2, 3]` возвращает тип `[i32; 3]` — массив с заданной при компляции длиной. Когда же `&[f64]` является *срезом* — ссылочным типом, состоящим из указателя на массив и длины (известной во время *выполнения*).

Вот так будет работать:

```
fn foo(a:&[&[f64]],x:&[f64])
{
    for i in 0..3 {
        for j in 0..4 {
            println!("{}",a[i][j]);
        }
    }
}

fn main()
{
    let a:[&[f64];3]=[&[1.1,-0.2, 0.1,1.6],
                       &[0.1,-1.2,-0.2,2.3],
                       &[0.2,-0.1, 1.1,1.5]];
    let x:[f64;3]=[0.0;3];

    foo(&a,&x);
}
```

> К сожалению их "книга" пока не богата на примеры передачи параметров в функцию.

Кроме собственно официальной документации по Rust существует очень хорошее руководство с множеством прекрасных примеров [Rust by Example](http://rustbyexample.com/).

Comment: Судя по тому, что функция работает с захардкожеными размерностями, можно просто поменять сигнатуру функции на `foo(a: [[f64; 3]; 4], [f64; 3])` и вообще не использовать ссылки нигде (убрать `&` отовсюду). Минусы: в стеке будут передаваться массивы полностью, вместо ссылок на них; для не-Copy типов данные будут исчезать при вызове `foo()`, которая будет «поглощать» переданные данные (семантика перемещения).

Answer (score 1):

Можно делать вот так, получается красивее всего:

```
fn foo<Matrix: AsRef<[Row]>, Row: AsRef<[f64]>>(a:Matrix,x:&[f64])
{
    for i in 0..3 {
        for j in 0..4 {
            println!("{}",a.as_ref()[i].as_ref()[j]);
        }
    }
}

fn main()
{
    let A:[[f64;4];3]=[[1.1,-0.2, 0.1,1.6],
                       [0.1,-1.2,-0.2,2.3],
                       [0.2,-0.1, 1.1,1.5]];
    let mut X:[f64;3]=[0.0;3];

    foo(&A,&X);
}
```

Но в этом случае длина массивов не должна превышать 32 (потолок для размерности массивов, для которых в компиляторе поддерживается реализация типажей, в числе которых `AsRef`/`AsMut`). Ждем реализации [параметризации размерностей](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/issues/1038).